# Retrofit 2: la aplicación no responde

Tags: java, android, webservice, retrofit

Estoy intentando hacer llamados múltiples para descargar archivos uno por uno desde Retrofit: el primero trae los nombres de archivos a descargar. Con esta lista, se deben ir descargando los archivos uno por uno. Pero tras ***esperar el primer llamado***, me sale lo siguiente:

[image: La aplicación no responde]

Eso ocasiona que no se pueda descargar nada ni que se pueda ejecutar lo implementado en el `onResponse(Call<?> call, Response<?> response)` de la instancia `Callback<?>`.

En el log de la aplicación, antes de colgarse, aparece esto:

```
04-26 13:16:46.259 25803-25834/com.kcht.naughtclock I/ViewRootImpl: ANR Key Analyze: No Key event currently.
04-26 13:16:46.260 25803-25834/com.kcht.naughtclock I/ViewRootImpl: ANR Key Analyze: Previeous Event null,finish at 1969-12-31 19:00:00.000
04-26 13:16:46.260 25803-25834/com.kcht.naughtclock I/ViewRootImpl: ANR Motion Analyze: No motion event currently.
04-26 13:16:46.260 25803-25834/com.kcht.naughtclock I/ViewRootImpl: ANR Motion Analyze: Previeous Event null,finish at 1969-12-31 19:00:00.000
04-26 13:16:46.341 25803-25828/com.kcht.naughtclock I/art: Thread[2,tid=25828,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xaf7dc000,peer=0x12c3b0a0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
04-26 13:16:46.562 25803-25828/com.kcht.naughtclock I/art: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

¿Por qué se está *colgando* la aplicación?

Comment: ¿Dónde estás ejecutando la llamada? ¿En el MainThread o en background?

Comment: Lo ejecuto en el MainThread

Comment: Pues ese es el motivo por el que la aplicación se cuelga, es una operación costosa por lo que debes ejecutarlo en background.  Hay muchas soluciones para esto, por ejemplo, si no tienes ninguna arquitectura montada, entonces puedes usar un callback.  Si tienes arquitectura, yo uso las corrutinas, son fáciles de testear y de implementar.

Comment: Busca en el LogCat donde diga Caused by , ahi se puede describir especificamente el problema, agregalo a tu pregunta.